# Tenho o seguinte problema na minha tupla

Tags: python

```
def convertFarenheit(n):
    return (n * (9/5)) + 32

def convertCelsius(n):
    return (n - 32) * (5/9)

def graus(temp1,escala1,temp2,escala2):
    dados = ()
    if escala1 == 'C' and escala2 == 'C':
        soma = temp1 + temp2
        dados = (soma, 'C')

    elif escala1 == 'F' and escala2 == 'F':
        soma = temp1 + temp2
        dados = (soma, 'F')

    elif escala1 == 'F' and escala2 == 'C':
        soma = convertCelsius(temp1) + temp2
        dados = (soma, 'C')

    elif escala1 == 'C' and escala2 == 'F':
        soma = convertFarenheit(temp1) + temp2
        dados = (soma, 'F')

    return dados
def main(): 
    temp1 = float(input())
    escala1 = input().upper()[0]

    temp2 = float(input())
    escala2 = input().upper()[0]
    print(graus(temp1,escala1,temp2,escala2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Exemplos de entradas:

- temp1 = -84.6
- escala1 = F
- temp2 = 15.7
- escala2 = C

Retorno vai ser : (-49.07777777777777, 'C').

Se colocar `fstring f{soma:.4f}` para poder arrendondar para 4 casas decimais irá retornar : ('-49.0778', 'C'), mas eu não quero que retorne com as aspas no float.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar.

Comment: ja fiz a alteração

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito, você quer arredondar o número sem transformá-lo em um **str**, correto?

Se for o caso, você deve seguir o seguinte fluxo:

Primeiro, arredonde o seu valor de temperatura. Depois, imprima ele (e não o que tentou realizar, onde fez tudo na chamada do **print**). Sempre um passo de cada vez.

E como arredonda **floats** em Python? Bom, um dos métodos é a função **round()**:

```
>>> temp = -49.07777777777777
>>> round(temp, 4)
-49.0778
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja implementar um código que seja capaz de realizar **conversões** de temperaturas e imprimir seus valores com **4 casas decimais**.

Pois bem, quando estamos trabalhando com conversões de temperaturas devemos deixar claro qual será:

1. A escala de entrada;
2. A escala de saída.

Pois, com estas informações iremos montar o código.

Uma das formas correta para se realizar conversões de temperaturas é:

```
def converte_fahrenheit():
    fahrenheit = (((temp * 9) / 5) + 32)
    return fahrenheit


def converte_celcius():
    celcius = ((5 * (temp - 32)) / 9)
    return celcius


# Capturando e tratando a escala de entrada
resp = input('Desejas digitar uma temperatura em °C ou °F? [C/F] ').upper()
while (len(resp) != 1) or (resp not in 'CF'):
    print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas a letra "C" ou "F"!\033[m')
    resp = input('Desejas digitar uma temperatura em °C ou °F? [C/F] ').upper()

# Verificando qual conversão será realizada
if resp == 'C':
    temp = float(input('Digite a temperatura em °C: '))
    converte_fahrenheit()

    print(f'{converte_fahrenheit():.4f} °F')
else:
    temp = float(input('Digite a temperatura em °F: '))
    converte_celcius()

    print(f'{converte_celcius():.4f} °C')
```

Observe que quando executamos o respectivo código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Desejas digitar uma temperatura em °C ou °F? [C/F]` . Neste momento devemos pressionar ou a tecla `C` ou a tecla `F`.

Se pressionarmos a tecla `C`, recebermos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite a temperatura em °C:`. Após termos digitado a temperatura em `°C`, o fluxo do código será direcionado para a função `converte_fahrenheit()`, onde a temperatura será convertida para `°F`.

Se pressionarmos a tecla `F`, recebermos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite a temperatura em °F:`. Após termos digitado a temperatura em `°F`, o fluxo do código será direcionado para a função `converte_celcius()`, onde a temperatura será convertida para `°C`.

Uma vez tendo realizado o conversão desejada, o valor será exibido com `4` casas decimais.